# Errors in the metadata manager. The process type specified for the Effect dimension is not valid since it is not processed

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Trying to hunt down an issue with an SSIS package we have and I don't know what to look for to help correct this issue.

Error:

```
Errors in the metadata manager. The process type specified for the Effect dimension is not valid since it is not processed.
```

I tried googling this and haven't seen anything that could point in a direction of what I should be looking at or checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to process the dimension with a type that needs the dimension to be processed. For instance, you are trying to do a process indexes, but the dimension is not previously processed.

Change the process indexes by a process update or a process complete.